# Convert a .xlsx file to .xls without losing data using Python

Tags: python, xlsx, xls

There was a need to convert the `.xlsx` file to `.xls`.

Existing types of solutions using `opepyxl` and `win32.com` lead to data loss, some formulary dependencies implemented in `.xlsx` formats.

Is there any module converting lossless formats to `.xlsx` to `.xls`?

Or maybe there is an advanced library for working with `.xlsx` files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993868/python-convert-read-save-excel-xlsx-to-xls

Comment: Does it work when converting from Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import openpyxl
import os

# get files
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
pdir = <<folder path in xlsx files are>>
filelist = [filename for filename in pdir.iterdir() if filename.suffix == '.xlsx']

for filename in filelist:
    print(filename.name)

for infile in filelist:
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(infile)
    outfile = f"{infile.name.split('.')[0]}.xls"
    workbook.save(outfile)
```

Source: https://python-forum.io/Thread-how-to-convert-xlsx-to-xls