# Outputting A .xls File In Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xls

I have been teaching myself Python to automate some of our work processes. So far reading from Excel files (.xls, .xlsx) has gone great.

Currently I have hit a bit of a snag. Although I can output .xlsx files fine, the software system that we have to use for our primary work task can only take .xls files as an input - it cannot handle .xlsx files, and the vendor sees no reason to add .xlsx support at any point in the foreseeable future.

When I try to output a .xls file using either Pandas or OpenPyXl, and open that file in Excel, I get a warning that the file format and extension of the file do not match, which leads me to think that attempting to open this file using our software could lead to some pretty unexpected consequences (because it's actually a .xlsx file, just not *named* as such)

I've tried to search for how to fix this all on Google, but all I can find are guides for how to convert a .xls file to a .xlsx file (which is almost the opposite of what I need). So I was wondering if anybody could please help me on whether this can be achieved, and if it can, how.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: not sure if it's possible in openpyxl, but you can read/write XLS in xlrd and xlwt modules

Comment: another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993868/python-convert-read-save-excel-xlsx-to-xls

Comment: I’m curious, why do you need to convert files to an Excel format which was deprecated twelve years ago?

Comment: Use xlrd and xlwt.

Comment: @Alexander Cécile - As I stated in the question, the software system we are forced to use, which is industry standard and also pretty much the only viable option in the field I'm in, can't handle any format except .xls. Even if we don't automate this process, we still would have no choice but to use .xls files. I have complained to the vendor about this, but they don't see any reason to change something that still technically works =/

Comment: @TigerBailey Ah yes your right, sorry. I completely forgot you stated that in your post. It’s not a great situation to be in, good luck :/ Out of curiosity, can you share what software this is?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile The software is Syllabus Plus, which is used for large scale educational institution (like, University, etc.) schedule planning and room usage and stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the [`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html#pandas-dataframe-to-excel) documentation you should notice a parameter called `engine`, which states:

> **engine** : *str*, optional
>
> Write engine to use, `openpyxl` or `xlsxwriter`. You can also set this via the options `io.excel.xlsx.writer`, `io.excel.xls.writer`, and `io.excel.xlsm.writer`.

What it does not state is that the `engine` param is automatically picked based on your file extension -- therefore, easy fix:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"data": [1, 2, 3]})
df.to_excel("file.xls") # Notice desired file extension.
```

This will automatically use the [`xlwt`](https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) engine, so make sure you have it installed via `pip install xlwt`.

Answer (score 1):

Felipe is right the filename extension will set the engine parameter.

So basically all it's saying is that the old Excel format ".xls" extension is no longer supported in Pandas. So if you specify the output spreadsheet with the ".xlsx" extension the warning message disappears.

Comment: Correct. When you specify 'xlsx', Pandas automatically uses the openpyxl package, which is not deprecated and works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY have the answer!
I have libreoffice installed and am using the following in the command line on windows:

```
"C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" --headless --convert-to xlsx test2.xls
```

Currently trying to use subprocess to automate this.

Comment: The question is asking to convert to xls, *not* xlsx.

Answer (score 0):

If your excel is Microsoft excel 97 then try this simple step:

import pandas as pd

import xlrd

data = pd.read_html('filename.xls')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).